# How to put a desktop entry into applications list in open-with dialogs?

Tags: .desktop

Here is my desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/home/kaiyin/workspace/python/python3_scripts/unz.py %f
MimeType=application/gzip;application/x-compressed-tar;application/zip;application/x-bzip;
Name=unz.py
NoDisplay=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility
```

Nautilus open-with dialog:

[image]

Dolphin open-with dialog:

[image]

So my app isn't in either.

Comment: Because tar is a terminal command, thunar needs a plugin, and unity does too.  Try installing an app like 7Zip from the Software Center, or use a Terminal

Comment: Did as your suggested, and still got the same result.

Comment: Put it in `~/.local/share/applications`… the `/home/kaiyin/workspace/python/python3_scripts/unz.py` must be marked as executable and add `application/x-bzip2`.